# How to disable upstream buffering Nginx + Docker + Gunicorn?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

I'm trying to use Nginx as proxy server between client and Gunicorn. Nginx, Gunicorn (Django) are Docker's containers. Problem is I can't disable buffering of upstream when I send large file from Client to Django App. TTFB time is quite small, thus my progress bar (which use xhr.upload.progress event) becomes 100% very fast (less than second). Then I have to wait 30 sec while file will be upload to server. Here are my settings. Please, help. I've tried many configurations trying to set buffer size to zero etc., check many answer on StackOverflow, but nothing helps.

docker-compose.yaml

```
...
    services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.4
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}
    env_file:
      - ./.env

  backend:
    build: ./src/backend
    volumes:
      - RUDZASV0021:/code/storage/RUDZASV0021
      - logs:/code/logs
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env

  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./src/frontend/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./docker-settings/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

Backend Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.7-slim

WORKDIR /code
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mc
CMD gunicorn entrypoints.wsgi:application --workers=4 --worker-class=gevent  --timeout=90 --graceful-timeout=10 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Nginx Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.20.0

WORKDIR /frontend
COPY ./src/frontend/dist .
WORKDIR /cert
COPY ./cert/device.key .
COPY ./cert/device.crt .
```

Nginx default.conf

```
upstream hello_django {
    server backend:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /cert/device.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /cert/device.key;

    client_max_body_size 2G;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    access_log /frontend/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /frontend/nginx-error.log;

    location / {
        root /frontend;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://hello_django;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After long investigation I have used following decision.

1. I had to change Gunicorn with uWSGI, because I found that "uwsgi_request_buffering off;" is properly working with Nginx + uWSGI
2. Create own upload handler in Django, which simultaneously write progress in data for any file (guid) and write temporary file to drive
3. After start uploading, push additional requests from frontend to backend (each 1 sec) asking for progress for particular file. I used two additonal header to specify folder id and file id, because in upload handler you can not access to request.GET and it's not so easy to get path parameters.

Nginx default.conf

```
...
location /api/ {
        uwsgi_pass hello_django;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_request_buffering off;
    }
```

Backend Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.7-slim

WORKDIR /code
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mc build-essential
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements.txt
CMD uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi.ini
```

uswgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
module=entrypoints.wsgi:application 
master=True 
pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid 
processes=5 
harakiri=300 
harakiri-verbose=True
max-requests=5000 
vacuum=True
single-interpreter=True
enable-threads=True
socket=0.0.0.0:8000
req-logger = file:/tmp/uwsgi_req.log
logger = file:/tmp/uwsgi_err.log
```

hadlers.py

```
from django.core.files.uploadhandler import TemporaryFileUploadHandler
from logic.domain import commands
from .views import bus
from django.conf import settings

class ProgressBarUploadHandler(TemporaryFileUploadHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._previous_start = 0

    @property 
    def _folder_id(self):
        return self.request.META['HTTP_X_FOLDER_ID']

    @property 
    def _id(self):
        return self.request.META['HTTP_X_FILE_ID']

    def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
        # Update upload Progress 
        if start >= self._previous_start + settings.UPLOAD_PROGRESS_INCREMENT_SIZE:
            cmd = commands.SetUploadProgress(self._folder_id, self._id, start + len(raw_data))
            bus.handle(cmd)
            self._previous_start = start

        super().receive_data_chunk(raw_data, start)

    def file_complete(self, file_size):
        # Update upload Progress 
        cmd = commands.SetUploadProgress(self._folder_id, self._id, file_size)
        bus.handle(cmd)
        # Delete old upload Progress 
        cmd = commands.DeleteOldUploadProgress()
        bus.handle(cmd)

        return super().file_complete(file_size)
```